# C# for Unity3d: 3x invalid tokens, name space cannot directly contain..., and end of file expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm trying to make a basic death script that changes the view from the main character controller to a second camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
    struct Death
{
if (isDead) //invalid token "if" and ")"
{
DeathCamTag.SetActive(true); //invalid token "("
}
else // a namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods
{
FPSControllerTag.SetActive(true);   
} 
} //type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

if I remove the struct at line 2, all the errors go away except the one on line 4 (if (isDead)) and it gets "a namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods"
I have a bit of experience with programming in python, C++, and Java, but I really just started c# yesterday, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I sort of fixed it, but now I get "the name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context", for isdead, deathcamtag, and fpscontrollertag, unless I change public class DeathCamSwitch to HealthScript, but then I get "the namespace '' already contrains a definition for 'healthscript'" so it doesn't work if I don't link the two classes but when I do, there's 2 definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your code to some method declaration. Also I would say that you have to use class instead of struct and inherit from `MonoBehaviour`

Here is an example of a simple scene changer class:

```
public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour {

    public string SceneName;

    void OnMouseDown(){

        Application.LoadLevel(SceneName);

    }
}
```